# How to perform a string replace in a SQL query using PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using PHP and SQL Server to first request an HTML template stored in my database, and then update it in a different table in the database based on form input from my website.

my update function in my model uses a get_template function to pull the text from the database, then updates the table.

```
public function update_domain_rules($template_content, $domain_guid) {


 $sql = "UPDATE domains
           SET rules = ?
           WHERE domain_guid = ?";  

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($template_content, $domain_guid));

return $query->result();

}
```

I need to be able to replace certain words in the template I pulled with variables in my controller, specifically the start date, end date, and the name of the domain that is selected in the dropdown, and then update the database.  this is the code for my controller:

```
function content()
    {
        $this->load->model('domains_model');
        $this->load->model('insert_rules_model');

        $domain_guid = $this->input->post('edit_domain_guid');
        $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');                  
        $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');                 
        $template = $this->input->post('select_template');  

        if ($start_date == '') {                    
            $start_date ==date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-1 day"));
        }

        if ($end_date =='') {
            $end_date ==date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-1 day"));  
        }

        $start_date_formatted = date_create($start_date);
        $end_date_formatted = date_create($end_date);


        $template_name = array(             //create array referenced in the form_dropdown in the view
        'aliens_ep1_template',
        'aliens_ep2_template',
        'zombies_ep1_template',
        'zombies_ep2_template'
        );

        $template_text = $this->insert_rules_model->get_template($template);            

        if ($template != null) {
            foreach ($template_text as $row) {
            $query = $this->insert_rules_model->update_domain_rules($row->template, $domain_guid);

            }
        }   


        //redirect ("admin/insert_rules");                  

        $data = array(
            'template_name' => $template_name,
            'domains' => $this->domains_model->domain_dropdown_list(),
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date' => $end_date,
            'domain_guid' => $domain_guid

        );

        $this->load->view('includes/header_admin');
        $this->load->view('admin/insert_rules', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer_admin'); 

}
```

I am very new to PHP so forgive me if my code looks ugly. I am just trying to get this thing to be functional.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to use the start_date, end_date, and name of the domain to replace certain words in my template before I update the domain table, if that makes sense.

the template is pulled using SQL in another function in my model - and then updated with the function I posted. I need to replace strings in the template before I update the table and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What does your template look like?  What are you trying to replace?  Have you tried anything?  You probably want something like [`str_replace`](https://secure.php.net/str_replace) or [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: it's an HTML template. (it's used to display rules for a game in an email that gets sent to all players of the game) I left occurences of #STARTDATE, #ENDDATE, and #DOMAIN in there, for every instance that needs to be replaced dynamically based on what's submitted in the form on my website. I'm actually really not sure where to start because the query returns an array of objects, not a simple string that I can do str_replace on.